# Batch Method with Argument

Tags: variables, batch-file, cmd

Is there a way to put a argument into a method in batch script? I know I can do that in java programming.

Example #1 (Java)

```
public class Test {

  public static void main (String [] args) {
    Test t1=new Test();
    System.out.print(t1.method1(false));
  }

  public int method1 (boolean val1) {

    if (val1==false) {
      return 0;}
    else {
      return 1;}
    }

  }
```

I want to have something like this so when the method runs, depending on the argument, the method will produce varying results.

Example #2 (Batch - partial pseudocode)

```
:method1
::With an argument a1 (by default a1=1)
if %a1%==1 echo Option #1
if %a1%==2 echo Option #2
```

So when I call method1, depending on the argument, I could have two results.
Is there a way to do that? Or suggestions on how one method can have different results? Thanx

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, since OP is obviously too lazy to do even the most basic research

Comment: Just googled the question title and the answers/tutorials/examples are in top-10 results...

Answer (score 0):

Try the inline help for the `call` built-in statement.

```
C:\>call /?
Calls one batch program from another.

CALL [drive:][path]filename [batch-parameters]

  batch-parameters   Specifies any command-line information required by the
                     batch program.

If Command Extensions are enabled CALL changes as follows:

CALL command now accepts labels as the target of the CALL.  The syntax
is:

    CALL :label arguments

A new batch file context is created with the specified arguments and
control is passed to the statement after the label specified.  You must
"exit" twice by reaching the end of the batch script file twice.  The
first time you read the end, control will return to just after the CALL
statement.  The second time will exit the batch script.  Type GOTO /?
for a description of the GOTO :EOF extension that will allow you to
"return" from a batch script.

<continutes>
```